# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 on HEROKU when deploying NODE.JS + MONGODB (CRUD APP)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my node.js project on Heroku but I keep on getting this error when I run `heroku open`

```
{"message":"connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000","name":"Error","stack":"Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16)","config":{"url":"http://localhost:3000/api/users","method":"get","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","User-Agent":"axios/0.21.1"},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1},"code":"ECONNREFUSED"}
```

My app runs perfectly on local server when I just run `npm start`

I have read many posts and seen many youtube videos but I could not find an answer to this error. I am very new to FULL STACK DEV and would appreciate your help.

Thank you

I HAVE entered the config variables using both the `heroku config:set` and using the Heroku Dashboard, here are the codes

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const path = require('path');

const connectDB = require('./server/database/connection');
const app = express();

dotenv.config( { path : 'config.env'} )
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

// log requests
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

// mongodb connection
connectDB();


// parse request to body-parser
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended : true}))

// set view engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
//app.set("views", path.resolve(__dirname, "views/ejs"))

// load assets
app.use('/css', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/css")))
app.use('/img', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/img")))
app.use('/js', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/js")))


// load routers
app.use('/', require('./server/routes/router'))

app.listen(process.env.PORT||PORT, ()=> { console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`)});
```

connection.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDB = async () => {
    try{
        //mongodb connection string
        const con =  await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI ,{
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
        })

        console.log(`MongoDB connected : ${con.connection.host}`);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

module.exports = connectDB
```

Procfile

```
web: npm start
```

config.env

```
PORT = 3000
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://admin_m:******@cluster0.dbljb.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "crud_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "evo-calendar": "^1.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jsdom": "^16.6.0",
    "jsdon": "^0.1.15",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "rrule": "^2.6.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and after a lot of trial and error found out the problem was with my **URL** which i was passing to the axios.get method to fetch the data from the database to render on my index page. **That URL was of localhost:3000** **which you need to update to the one provided by heroku** after deploying the app.

Also better way is to use the baseURL property of Axios to set your URL once only and use it accordingly for development and production environments